# Writing JSDoc correctly for WebStorm, React

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jsdoc

I've written the following JSDoc, and when I view it in rendered view, it doesn't seem to render in a nice way. The text all flows into each other, and many of the property descriptions aren't showing up. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Shows the Roster Structure on the Rules and Scoring page.
 *
 * @param {string} [leagueAbbr]
 * When provided, the following text will be added to the description:
 *   "and must include players from at least 2 different {leagueAbbr} games."
 * If including lineupDescriptionOverride, this prop should not be used.
 *
 * @param {string} [lineupDescriptionOverride]
 * Provide the entire lineup description text.
 * If including this prop, leagueAbbr should not be used.
 *
 * @param {string} [lineupDescriptionAddendum]
 * Provide text to add after the default text ("Lineup will consist of....from at least 2 {leagueAbbr} games").
 *
 * @param {Object[]} sections
 * Data for the lineup structure.
 *
 * @param {number} sections[].count
 * Number of players in the section.
 *
 * @param {string} sections[].positionHeader
 * Text to appear above the icon.
 *
 * @param {string} sections[].positionText
 * Text to appear below the icon.
 *
 * @param {string} [sections[].iconSrc]
 * Provide a custom icon url for the section.
 *
 * @param {string} iconSrc
 * url for the icon.
 *
 * @param {string} [playerNamePlural]
 * Provide text to replace the default text ("players") in "Lineup will consist of # *players*".
 *
 * @returns {JSX.Element}
 * The roster component
 */
```

[image]

Comment: your comment is rendered fine for me in 2021.3; what IDE version do you use?

Comment: @lena WS 2021.3 Build #WS-213.5744.224, built on November 27, 202

Comment: strange, I'm using the same version, but the result of previewing the comment look different...

Comment: Strange indeed. I also didn't see anything interesting from searching settings for "jsdoc"